# On a related list of a custom object, is it possible to show fields of a related custom object

Tags: page-layout, related-list

Apologies if I am asking a stupid question here, but here is my scenario:

I have a custom object, say **A**, which has two lookups: 
One to a standard object (**Lead**) and, 
 
Another to a custom object, say **B**.

The name of the two lookups on **A** are **B__c** and **Lead__c**.

Now, on the related list for **A** on **Lead's** page-layout, how can I show the fields belonging to **B**? Is it even possible? The user interface doesn't seem to allow me to do this, but I was trying to use something like:

```
<relatedLists>
    <fields>B__c.some_custom_field__c</fields>
    <relatedList>A__c.Lead__c</relatedList>
</relatedLists>
```

in the layout metadata file, but it doesn't work. I get a message that says something like:
**Invalid field in related list...**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show complete related list.  However, you can show only fields.

To get fields from B to A, use the below fields

```
A__c.B__r.Name

A__c.B__r.Id

A__c.B__r.someCustomFieldOnB__c
```

Comment: in addition to sfdcFanBoy's answer, if you are able to convert B's relationship field from look up to master detail on A object, you dont need formula fields. you can easily put B's fields on related list on Lead page layout.